# Creating a modal with JS based on a link selected

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getId(id) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
    
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    modal.style.display = "block";
    
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#main{  left: 0px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;}
    
#main p{    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: .8em;
            text-align: justify;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            margin-top: 25px;}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: center;
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Modal Body */
.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

/* Modal Footer */
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- main body of the HTML -->
<div id="main" >
                <h1>Current Members</h1>
                <center>
                    <table width="75%" border="0">
                        <th>Committee Members</th>
                            <tr height="50">
                                <td><a href="#" id="howie" onClick="getId(this.id+"-modal")">Howie Jones (President)</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" id="ferdi" onClick="getId(this.id)">Fernando Russo (V.P.)</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" id="ste" onClick="getId(this.id)">Steve Dicksons (Secretary)</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" id="kym" onClick="getId(this.id)">Kym Jones (Treasurer)</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        <th>Members</th>
                            <tr height="50">
                                <td><a href="#" id="john" onClick="getId(this.id)">John Ketley</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" id="mike" onClick="getId(this.id)">Mike Lamb</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" id="sol" onClick="getId(this.id)">Sol Dean</a></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </div>
      
<!-- modal in the same HTML file -->
  <div id="howie-modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
                    <p>Some other text...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp for the basis of adding a simple modal view to my HTML page. As I have mulptiple links on my main page, I have modified the JS to the following

```
function getId(id) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    modal.style.display = "block";

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
             modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

with the caller code looking like this

```
<center>
    <table width="75%" border="0">
        <th>Committee Members</th>
            <tr height="50">
                <td><a href="#" id="howie" onClick="getId(this.id)">Howie Jones (President)</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" id="ferdi" onClick="getId(this.id)">Fernando Russo (V.P.)</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" id="ste" onClick="getId(this.id)">Steve Dicksons (Secretary)</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" id="kym" onClick="getId(this.id)">Kym Jones (Treasurer)</a></td>
            </tr>
        <th>Members</th>
            <tr height="50">
                <td><a href="#" id="john" onClick="getId(this.id)">John Ketley</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" id="mike" onClick="getId(this.id)">Mike Lamb</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" id="sol" onClick="getId(this.id)">Sol Dean</a></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

The issue is that when I click one of the links, the modal isn't displayed and the link vanishes.

The modal id for each modal is set to whatever is passed when the link is clicked (for example `<div id="howie" class="modal">`

When I run this through the webtools in Mozilla, no errors are picked up from the JS and the code is being executed.

I've never done something like this before, so chances are I've made a newbie error. I did consider creating the modal and have that modal load a webpage, but same thing applies - not sure how to do that in JS.

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document (so two elements cannot have the same ID). Make your modals have the same ID, but with "-modal" appended, then use `getId(this.id + "-modal")`.

Comment: Are you using a framework like bootstrap or plain vanilla JS  and CSS?

Comment: @Japsz - just vanilla JS and CSS

Comment: @HereticMonkey - all the element ids are different, so shouldn't really need to append -modal to the this.id part (I'm not even sure it would work as the first line of the JS does a getElementById - or are we talking at cross purposes here?)

Comment: You have a link. It has an id of `howie`. You have a modal element that contains what you want to show in the modal, right? It has an id of `howie`. That's two elements with the same id. If you don't have the modal element (and, now that I look at your example, it's not there), then what are you expecting to show up when you click the link? Though you do mention `<div id="howie" class="modal">`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I've added the -modal in the call the JS, still nothing showing. Have I got this correct? `<a href="#" id="howie" onClick="getId(this.id+"-modal")">Howie Jones (President)</a>` ? The div for the modal is now id="howie-modal"

Comment: Yeah, that should work, unless there's something wrong elsewhere in the code.  Hard to say without a [mre].

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I've added the code as it appears here for you. When I run the webtools on the code, no errors appear, but then no modal appears either

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at your code close enough. It should be `onclick="getId(this.id + '-modal')"` You need to use single quotes in the function since you have double quotes for the attribute. One of the many reasons to use `addEventListener` instead of inline event handler attributes.